# Обновление значений в базе данных

Tags: python, sql

Я записываю 2 значения в базу данных таким орбазом:

В одной из функции: zapis(message.chat.id, 0)

Этой функцией является:

```
def zapis(user_id, Type):
    with sqlite3.connect(path_to_db) as db:
        db.execute("INSERT INTO storage "
                   "(user_id, Type) "
                   "VALUES (?, ?)",
                   [user_id, Type])
        db.commit()
```

После чего, мне требуется ОБНОВИТЬ эту базу данных вот таким значением:

zapis_type(message.chat.id, Type='Text')

```
def zapis_type(user_id, Type):
    with sqlite3.connect(path_to_db) as db:
        db.execute(f"UPDATE storage SET Type={str('TEXT')} WHERE user_id={user_id}")
        db.commit()
```

И после чего выдаёт вот такую вот ошибку, как пишет Visual Studio:

> Exception has occurred: OperationalError (note: full exception trace is shown but execution is paused at: process_message)
> no such column: TEXT

Answer (score 0):

Ваша проблема в форматировании в этой строке:

`db.execute(f"UPDATE storage SET Type={str('TEXT')} WHERE user_id={user_id}")`
Функция `str` никакого отношения к интерпретации переданного параматра базой данных не имеет. В итоге база получает строку

`UPDATE storage SET Type=TEXT WHERE user_id=1`
и вполне логично ищет поле TEXT.

Правильный вариант:

`db.execute(f"UPDATE storage SET Type='{'TEXT'}' WHERE user_id={user_id}")`
ковычки вынесены в запрос.

PS: проблемы правда на этом не заканчиваются, поработайте над неймингом своих функций и почитайте про sql-инъекции.